# Understanding SQL Alchemy Contains Eager

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm

I want to filter User's query by Order
Both User and Order are models.
Order has a relationship with User -> `order = db.relationship(Order, lazy=True)`
order.placed_on is a date.

The problem is that the code has a very slow response time (9 seconds), so i wanted to optimize it, so i came across loading relationships without querying

I don't know how to do this

```
# Code snippet needed to be optimized perhaps
query = User.query
query = query.join(Order).filter(func.extract('week', Order.placed_on).in_(weeks))
```

```
def get_tracker(admin):
    query = User.query.filter_by(is_deleted=False)
    tracker = request.json.get('tracker')
    weeks = set(map(int, request.json['week']))
    delivery_dates = tracker['deliveryDates']
    payment_status = tracker['paymentStatus']
    if payment_status == "Active":
       query = query.filter(User.delivery_count < User.total_delivery_count)
    elif payment_status == "One Delivery Left":
        query = query.filter(User.total_delivery_count - User.delivery_count == 1)    
    elif payment_status == 'Completed':
        query = query.filter(User.total_delivery_count == User.delivery_count)
    elif payment_status == 'Pending':
        query = query.filter(User.delivery_count > User.total_delivery_count)
    
    delivery_dates = [datetime.strptime(del_date, "%Y-%m-%d").date() for del_date in delivery_dates]
    query = query.filter(User.next_delivery_date.in_(delivery_dates))

    total_users = query.count()
    query = query.order_by(User.id.desc())
    query = query.join(Order).filter(func.extract('week', Order.placed_on).in_(weeks))

    # Apply contains_eager to specify eager loading of the Order object
    query = query.options(contains_eager(Order.placed_on))
    result = []
    for user in query:
        temp = {"user": {"id": user.id, "first_name": user.first_name, "last_name": user.last_name,
         "delivery_count": user.delivery_count, "total_delivery_count": user.total_delivery_count,
         "paymentStatus" : user.payment_status, "last_delivery_date": user.last_delivery_date,
          "mobile_number": user.mobile_number}, "books": []}
        for order in user.order:
            temp['books'].append(order.book.to_json() | {
                'is_refused': order.is_refused,
                'is_completed': order.is_completed,
                'is_taken': order.is_taken,
                'placed_on': order.placed_on,
            })
                
        result.append(temp)
    
    return jsonify({
        "status": "success",
        "data": result,
        "total_users" : total_users
    })
```

Someone suggested me to use contains_eager to optimize but i can't figure out how it works, i have read the docs and their example but i don't have much knowledge on SQL Alchemy.